# Spoiler tag stays revealed?

Tags: discussion, support

The [editing help](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page simply says the following with regards to spoiler tags:

> Spoilers
>
> To hide a certain piece of text and **have it only be visible when a
>   user moves the mouse over it**, use the blockquote syntax with an
>   additional exclamation point:
>
> At the end of episode five, it turns out that
>
> > he's actually his father.

Everyone knows that, when on a desktop computer, it will reveal the text if you hover the mouse over the spoiler. However I just accidentally found out that, after hovering and revealing the spoiler, if you click on it once then the spoiler *remains* *revealed* even if you move the mouse away!

**Is this a brand new feature? Or has it always been like that?**

Comment: Probably a side-effect from adding that functionality for touchscreen devices (tablets and phones).

Comment: It's been that way for quite a while.

Comment: @alexwlchan hmm, is there  the site says that for new users to know?

Comment: If you click it a second time, the spoiler will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. It was implememnted a long, long, time ago on a server far, far away.